# storing apex_item.select_list_from_lov selection

Tags: oracle-apex

[image]I have an LOV in my HTML page that I created with APEX_ITEM.SELECT_LIST_FROM_LOV

Should I also create a Page Item for it?

I mean I am a bit confused because this item has no name as they got if I 'd create an LOV as PAGE ITEM.

How should I get the selected value to insert it for example, into apex_collections?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why did you create it that way?  If you only want one select list based on an LOV on your page, use a page item.  APEX_ITEM package is normally used only when manually creating tabular forms where the same LOV will appear on multiple report rows.

Comment: I can 't place individual page items whereever I want on the page. I need to use 20~ of lov and textboxes all around the webpage.

Comment: I think you can - where did you want it?

Comment: htp.p('
{...}
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td colspan="5" rowspan="2" valign="top" width="375">Service quality refers to effort that ..</td>
  <td rowspan="2">'
  ||v_qos_weight
  ||'</td>
{...}
');

Comment: Looked bad without text-formating, sorry. I simply want to use them in html table cells

Comment: Can you post an image of the page?  It's hard to visualise what you mean!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the value of an item created using the APEX_ITEM package by looking at the PL/SQL array apex_application.g_fNN where "NN" is the number you used as the first parameter to the APEX_ITEM function.

For example, if you used APEX_ITEM like this:

```
apex_item.select_list_from_lov(42, 'MY_LOV')
```

then you can get the values like this:

```
for i in 1..apex_application.g_f42.count loop
   l_value := apex_application.g_f42(i);
end loop;
```

(If you had used APEX_ITEM in a multi-row report then there will be more than 1 element in the array.)

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I was looking for :) Now I can get my selected values :)